# Issues related to GtkToplevelAccessible in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gtk, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run voyant-tool in Ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk version "1.8.0_242" and getting following error: GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:59:29.522: invalid cast from 'GtkToplevelAccessible' to 'JawToplevel'. The GUI is opening but not allowing to select any option. The same is running happily in Ubuntu 16,04 with the same Java version. Tried a couple of quick fix after Googling it but not able to solve it.

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Comment: Thanks. It has worked for Ubuntu 20.04 (with openjdk 11). Thanks a lot.